# Add a delay with raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like, when my raycaster intersect an object during 2 sec, update the texture of an object.

So i try to use clock fonction but not sure to understand how to use it.

```js
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
clock.autoStart = true;

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( pickable, true );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    if (!clock.running) clock.start() 
    
    if (clock.getElapsedTime() > 2) {
        if (intersects[0].object.name === "btn_meeting_01") {
            mesh_sphere.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/DIVE_IMMO_00004.jpg");
        }
        if (intersects[0].object.name === "btn_lobby_01") {
            mesh_sphere.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/DIVE_IMMO_00003.jpg");
        }
        if (intersects[0].object.name === "btn_restaurant_01") {
            mesh_sphere.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/DIVE_IMMO_00002.jpg");
        }
        if (intersects[0].object.name === "btn_entrance_01") {
            mesh_sphere.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/DIVE_IMMO_00001.jpg");
        }
        if (intersects[0].object.name === "btn_exterior") {
            mesh_sphere.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/DIVE_IMMO_00000.jpg");
        };
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it using a boolean and a setTimeout
I assume that there is a better way to do it, but this is the idea
This is how I did it:

```js
var loading = false
var timeout = null

function render() {
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( pickable, true )

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    updateTexture()
  } else {
    resetLoader()
  }

  // Render the scene
}

function resetLoader() {
  if( loading ) {
    clearTimeout( timeout )

    loading = false
  }
}

function updateTexture() {
  if( !loading ) {
    timeout = setTimeout( function() {
      // Change your texture
    }, 2000 )

    loading = true
  }
}
```

Comment: i try but this doesn't want to render (black screen): const render = () => {
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( pickable, true );

   if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    updateTexture()
  } else {
    resetLoader()
  }
  effect.render(scene, camera);
}

Comment: For something as long as 2 seconds this is how I'd do it.